How to check if my PWA is installed in TMS WEB Core?
I have written a "TMS WEB PWA Application" in Delphi which allows users to install the web app on their devices.
The PWA app works well, I'm able to install it. On Windows, it gives a popup like this:

But now, How do I know when it has been installed? Is there a way in TMS WEB Core to check whether my PWA has been installed or not?
Seems like it is possible if I look at the PWA docs, but is there a "Delphi way" of checking in TMS WEB Core?
